# How to access Boolean expressions using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

Below is Excel.

[image]

Explanation : I have to delete **CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY and SUB_CATEGORY_2** data if **Filter** column has > 0 value (Should remove NAN, 0 and negative values)

Expected output:

[image]

Below is the script i tried.

```py
    def TEST(file):
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        mask = (df['Filter'] != 0).dropna()
        if mask:
            df1 = df[mask]
            df1['CATEGORY'] = ''
            df1['SUB_CATEGORY'] = ''
            df1['SUB_CATEGORY_2'] = ''
        print (df1)
    TEST("test.xlsx")
```

I am getting below error, 
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Please help me.

Comment: Yes, I tried with *mask.any()* operator, but while printing df it gives empty columns in Categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
where=df['Filter'].eq(0)| ( df['Filter'].isnull() | df['Filter'].eq('') )
cols=['CATEGORY','SUB_CATEGORY','SUB_CATEGORY_2']
df[cols]=df[cols].where(where)
```

**Here is an example**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Modules':'M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 8'.split(),'Filter':[1 ,3 ,6, np.nan, 0 ,np.nan ,2, 0],
                 'CATEGORY':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'data','data','data',np.nan,'data'],
                'SUB_CATEGORY':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'data','data','data',np.nan,'data'],
                'SUB_CATEGORY_2':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'data','data','data',np.nan,'data']})

  Modules  Filter CATEGORY SUB_CATEGORY SUB_CATEGORY_2
0      M1     1.0      NaN          NaN            NaN
1      M2     3.0      NaN          NaN            NaN
2      M3     6.0      NaN          NaN            NaN
3      M4     NaN     data         data           data
4      M5     0.0     data         data           data
5      M6     NaN     data         data           data
6      M7     2.0      NaN          NaN            NaN
7       8     0.0     data         data           data
```

---

```
where=df['Filter'].eq(0)| ( df['Filter'].isnull() | df['Filter'].eq('') )
cols=['CATEGORY','SUB_CATEGORY','SUB_CATEGORY_2']
df[cols]=df[cols].where(where,'')
print(df)

  Modules  Filter CATEGORY SUB_CATEGORY SUB_CATEGORY_2
0    M1      1.0                                      
1    M2      3.0                                      
2    M3      6.0                                      
3    M4      NaN    data       data          data     
4    M5      0.0    data       data          data     
5    M6      NaN    data       data          data     
6    M7      2.0                                      
7     8      0.0    data       data          data
```